# Wunderlist Api Update Reminder error

Tags: api, curl, task, wunderlist

I want update reminder for task in Wunderlist.
Use Wunderlist Api:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Access-Token: xxx" -H "X-Client-ID: xxx" a.wunderlist.com/api/v1/reminders/12345 -X PATCH -d {"revision":1,"date":"2015-11-25T16:49:23"}
```

and response:

> {"error":{"type":"not_found","translation_key":"api_error_not_found","message":"The
>   resource you requested could not be found."}}

Answer (score 0):

For your curl request, the server is actually seeing this as parameter

```
{revision:1,date:2015-11-25T16:49:23}
```

But I think your valid json should be:

```
{"revision":1,"date":"2015-11-25T16:49:23"}
```

So the valid parameter from your curl should be as below with wrapped inside quote. I used double quote by assuming that you are doing from windows. If from unix, you can easily use single quote for the wrapping!

```
-d "{\"revision\":1,\"date\":\"2015-11-25T16:49:23\"}"
```

Comment: From OS X. Use your solution, respone {"error":"bad_request"}